# Global Timer Interrupt for Time in Microcontroller

Tags: c, timer, interrupt, msp430

I have a lot of different time to keep track of in my design, but nothing is super critical.  10ms +/- a few ms isn't a big deal at all.  But there might be 10 different timers that are all counting at different periods at the same time, which obviously I don't have enough dedicated timers to support each of those in their own independent timer in the MSP-430.

My solution is to create a single ISR for an MSP-430 micro timer that fires at 1 KHz.  It simply increments an unsigned long for each ISR entry (so each tick is 1 ms).  Then elsewhere in my code I can use the SET_TIMER and EXPIRED define calls below to check to see if a certain amount of time has elapsed.    My question is, is this a good way to keep a "global" time?

**Timer Definitions:**

```
typedef unsigned long TIMER;
extern volatile TIMER Tick;
#define SET_TIMER(t,i) ((t)=Tick+(i))
#define EXPIRED(t) ((long)((t)-Tick)<0)
```

**Timer Interrupt Service Routine:**

```
void TIMER_B0_ISR(void)
{
    Tick++;
}
```

**Example usage in a single file:**

```
case DO_SOMETHING:
    if (EXPIRED(MyTimer1))
    {
        StateMachine = DO_SOMETHING_ELSE;
        SET_TIMER(MyTimer1, 100);
    }
    break;

case DO_SOMETHING_ELSE:
    if (EXPIRED(MyTimer1))
    ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Your scheme is relatively costly to check for timer wraparound - that you don't seem to do, currently (You need to check for it in all places where you check for "time expired" - That is the reason why you normally want only one such place).

I typically use a sorted linked list of timer expiration entries with the list head as the timer that is going to expire earliest. The ISR then only has to check this single entry and can directly notify that one single subscriber.

Comment: That sounds like a great idea! Any chance you have an example of that?

Comment: @Russell That is commercial code. Sorry, no chance.